# Show personalized error message in browser if exif_imagetype() is not available

Tags: php

I want to check if php extenstion  “exif_imagetype()” is installed and loaded or not in php.

In other words I want to show personalized error message in browser if exif_imagetype() is not available instead of log error “PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function exif_imagetype()”

My code is

```
if (exif_imagetype($fileTmpName) != IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {
    $message =  "Sorry, your file is not a valid JPG image.";
    return $message;
}
```

Comment: what was the error or problem

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.function-exists.php